Trying to utilize Supabase S3 Storage with Django
if USE_S3:
    # aws settings
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.getenv("SUPA_ACCESS_KEY_ID")
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.getenv("SUPA_SECRET_KEY")
    AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = "images"
    AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = os.getenv("SUPA_S3_REGION_NAME")
    AWS_ENDPOINT_URL = os.getenv("SUPA_S3_DOMAIN")
    # s3 static settings
    STATIC_LOCATION = "static"
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = "storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage"
    # s3 public media settings
    DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = "storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage"
else:
    STATIC_URL = "/static/"
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles_build", "static")
    MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media/")

STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),)

WARNINGS:
?: (staticfiles.W004) The directory '/Users/admin/Desktop/code/Zions_AutoERP/Zions_AutoERP/static' in the STATICFILES_DIRS setting does not exist.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/admin/Desktop/code/Zions_AutoERP/Zions_AutoERP/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/admin/Desktop/code/Zions_AutoERP/Zions_AutoERP/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/admin/Desktop/code/Zions_AutoERP/Zions_AutoERP/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/admin/Desktop/code/Zions_AutoERP/Zions_AutoERP/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 436, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/admin/Desktop/code/Zions_AutoERP/Zions_AutoERP/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 412, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/admin/Desktop/code/Zions_AutoERP/Zions_AutoERP/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 458, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/admin/Desktop/code/Zions_AutoERP/Zions_AutoERP/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 209, in handle
    collected = self.collect()
  File "/Users/admin/Desktop/code/Zions_AutoERP/Zions_AutoERP/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 135, in collect
    handler(path, prefixed_path, storage)
  File "/Users/admin/Desktop/code/Zions_AutoERP/Zions_AutoERP/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 368, in copy_file
    if not self.delete_file(path, prefixed_path, source_storage):
  File "/Users/admin/Desktop/code/Zions_AutoERP/Zions_AutoERP/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 278, in delete_file
    if self.storage.exists(prefixed_path):
  File "/Users/admin/Desktop/code/Zions_AutoERP/Zions_AutoERP/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/storages/backends/s3.py", line 514, in exists
    self.connection.meta.client.head_object(Bucket=self.bucket_name, Key=name)
  File "/Users/admin/Desktop/code/Zions_AutoERP/Zions_AutoERP/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 565, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/Users/admin/Desktop/code/Zions_AutoERP/Zions_AutoERP/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 958, in _make_api_call
    api_params = self._emit_api_params(
  File "/Users/admin/Desktop/code/Zions_AutoERP/Zions_AutoERP/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 1084, in _emit_api_params
    self.meta.events.emit(
  File "/Users/admin/Desktop/code/Zions_AutoERP/Zions_AutoERP/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 412, in emit
    return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/admin/Desktop/code/Zions_AutoERP/Zions_AutoERP/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 256, in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
  File "/Users/admin/Desktop/code/Zions_AutoERP/Zions_AutoERP/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 239, in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/admin/Desktop/code/Zions_AutoERP/Zions_AutoERP/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/handlers.py", line 282, in validate_bucket_name
    if not VALID_BUCKET.search(bucket) and not VALID_S3_ARN.search(bucket):
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

I've tried following a couple of other tutorials on how to use S3 based storages, but haven't been able to figure out how to get it working with Supabase. I get a type error for bucket name, but don't know much else about whats going on.

On my Django version, I just add this to settings.py and it works well.
STORAGES = {
    "staticfiles": {
        "BACKEND": "django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage",
    },
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "storages.backends.s3.S3Storage",
        "OPTIONS": {
            "access_key": os.environ.get("SUPABASE_S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID"),
            "secret_key": os.environ.get("SUPABASE_S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"),
            "bucket_name": os.environ.get("SUPABASE_S3_BUCKET_NAME"),
            "region_name": os.environ.get("SUPABASE_S3_REGION_NAME"),
            "endpoint_url": os.environ.get("SUPABASE_S3_ENDPOINT_URL"),
        },
    },
}

Those values are accesible in you supabase project settings.
